# array operation in matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab

I am a newbie at MATLAB and apologies if this question is already repeated.

I have a matrix, where each row is a vector. I am trying to normalise each vector into a unit.
I have tried the following

```
   vector_b=zeros(1,1);
    normVector_b=zeros(1,1);
     for i=1:3
       b=a(i,:);
         vector_b=[vector_b,b];
           norm_b=b/norm(b);
            normVector_b=[normVector_b,norm_b];
          end
```

I am able to extract each row vector and normalise it but I have to intilise the vector_b and normVector_b to some values without which I get a pre allocation error. 
But if I initailize this the first element in the result is

```
0    0.2673    0.5345    0.8018    0.4558    0.5698    0.6838    0.5026    0.5744    0.6462
```

I am wondering if there is any way I can get rid of the first 0 ?

Thanks,
Bhavya

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
vector_b=[];
normVector_b=[];
...
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what the issue is with pre allocation, because strictly speaking, matlab doesn't require it for matrices. The leading zero you put in yourself in `vector_b=[vector_b,b];` where `vector_b` is initially a zero. Same goes for `normVector_b`

Anyway, this should work:

```
% test matrix
test = [1 2 3 4; 5 6 7 8 ; 9 10 11 12];

%  reserve space for result
res = zeros(size(test));

%  loop over rows
for i = 1:1:size(test, 1)
    res(i, :) = test(i, :)./sqrt(sum(test(i, :).^2));
end
```

Comment: thank you very much for this information, but in case I am not sure of the size that I need to allocate for the res, then how can i initialize it to a default value ?

Comment: @Maurits - you can use `norm(test)` rather than `sqrt(...).^2`.

Comment: @Bhavya - `res` will take the same size as `test` - if you know `test`, you know `size(res)`. If `test` isn't defined at the time `res` is, you could just initialize it to an empty matrix.

Comment: @Bhavya, matlab does not require pre allocation for matrices, you can do it for speed. The code will run with out the `res=zeros()` line. See the [matlab matrix introduction](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/learn_matlab/f2-644.html)  
  
@strictlyrude27 I did that so that it is completely clear what `norm()` does in this context.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a vectorized solution:

```
%# some random matrix
a = random(10,4);

%# b(i,:) = a(i,:) ./ norm(a(i,:))
b = bsxfun(@rdivide, a, sqrt(sum(a.^2,2)))
```